# Can this be done with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm making a vector drawing application with OpenGL. Is there a way to implement a clipping mask? Ex: if I have Circle A and Circle B, I only want to see the part of circle B which intersects into Circle A's space. Is there a way to do this that isn't very expensif, I do not want to kill my application.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jex,

A quick google search for "clipping mask in openGL" had [this](http://wiki.daimi.au.dk/cpn2000/clipping_in_opengl.wiki) as the first result.

Comment: Blending is a different operation, but maybe you could find a blending operator and right set of colors to achieve same effect. However, it restricts your possibilities. Stencil buffer is the correct, established way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to draw Circle A into the stencil buffer, then draw Circle B.